# Meteor Package: Add Custom Options

Tags: meteor

I've created a Meteor smart package, and would like to add user generated custom options to the API.

However, **I'm having issues due to Meteor's automatic load ordering**.

```
SocialButtons.config({
  facebook: false
});
```

This runs a config block that adds defaults.

```
SocialButtons.config = function (options) {
  ... add to options if valid ...
};
```

Which in turn grabs a set of defaults:

```
var defaults = {
  facebook: true,
  twitter: true
}
```

Which are mixed into the settings.

```
var settings = _.extend(defaults, options);

...(program starts, uses settings)...
```

The problem is that everything must run in the proper order.

1. Create SocialButtons object
2. Run the optional SocialButtons.config()
3. Create settings & run the program

**How can I control the load order in Meteor without knowing where a user might place the optional configuration?**

Step 2 will be in a different folder/file, but must run sandwiched between steps 1 & 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.

1. Put your package into a `/lib` directory.
2. Include a setup function that sets the settings when called, and loads the data
3. Return the data from the startup function

In this case:

```
SocialButtons.get = function () {
   return initButtons();
}

function initButtons() { ... settings, startup, return final value ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really control load order right now so it's not guaranteed but placing files at `/libs` are loaded first but in your case it's doesn't really matter it might be something else here is a very simple package you can view the source on how I setup default options and allow to replace those easily https://github.com/voidale/meteor-bootstrap-alerts

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I noticed you used "Meteor.startup()" for initializing. I took a slightly different path, I'll post below.